Strongly considering dropping my PhD for jobs I want that don't require a PhD anyway. Looking for insight
I'm bringing this question here and this time it should be hopefully phrased in a more general way and others find it applicable. I've seriously considered dropping my PhD lately for practical reasons. As much as I want to finish it, I've had multiple job interviews for great jobs over the past two years that used my degrees. They passed on me because I was still a student technically. I'm only at this crossroads because gaining a job that's a fit for my skillset and could help build a career is like finding gold for an autistic individual like myself. I get that my gold analogy can easily be flipped and apply to a PhD too (as in, it can be seen as gold since only 2% of the US population has one), but given the vast number of underemployed autistic individuals and the fact I was almost always so close to being one of the 15% of autistic individuals who weren't that at multiple points is making me think I shouldn't keep kicking the can down the road and go straight to work ASAP once vocational rehabilitation helps me find a job.
This is going to mean returing the $11k of fellowship money I have saved right now (and haven't touched since I'm still living on my savings from my visiting instructor job), but that's a meager amount in the long run. That's also not mentioning that I'm going to need to live off that money until May 2025 if I stay the route of finishing my PhD and not gaining outside employment to finish my dissertation.
Would the potential job prospects I have at the moment outweigh the importance of getting a PhD? Especially given I likely get a job when it's hard for my demographic to do so otherwise? I'm also open to any other input as well.

What's the question?

@Allure Edited in the questions at the bottom and left it open for thoughts too.

You don’t have a job until you actually have a job. A potential job prospect is not a job. A job promise is not a job. A verbal job offer is not a job. Unless you have a contract ready to sign, you don’t have a job. Don’t rely on a previously stated rejection reason being true or the only reason; just getting rid of that one reason doesn’t mean you have a job.

We’re rehashing the same ground over and over again. Talk to your advisor, look for jobs, and keep working on your PhD. You’re getting all excited about this technician job that may or may not exist. Once you have a real offer on the table, you can decide about quitting the PhD.

Would the potential job prospects I have at the moment outweigh the importance of getting a PhD? Nobody can answer this for you without knowing your personal circumstances; you must do the work yourself. Go to your local jobs portal and search for the open positions, see how many positions there are that need a PhD and how many do not. As long as you're a PhD student you can also seek help at your university's career center.

And once again, you can ask your parents, because it seems like you have no idea what a job search is like, while they probably have done it before (possibly several times).

I never make life decisions based on abstract possibilities. I would only consider dropping a PhD after getting a job offer and would only actually do it after signing the contract. So for me prospects would never outweigh anything. This is how I live my life, you might want to follow the same method or not.

@cag51 I get the question is closed now, but the only listed action I see no point in is working on my PhD. I believe that looking for jobs that don't require it now means I shouldn't waste my time doing my PhD anymore. That's just my take. If you disagree, feel free to express that.

@Allure I applied to around 60 jobs last academic year. I managed to get a lecturer job offer (that I declined because teaching made me miserable and students disliked me) and a summer internship as well as a couple of job interviews. I have a coach who has helped me a few times here and there with job searches, but I'll admit I'm finding some limitations with her at this point other than the generic resume and cover letter updates and clean ups. My parents also have no degrees and never applied for any jobs in the online era in their lives so they can't help.

@MisterMiyagi I see where you're coming from but, just to elaborate on another reply, I don't see the point in continuing to work on my PhD if a potential job offer means quitting anyway. I know it's only a possibility, I'm aware it's "abstract," but I don't want to invest time into my PhD just to have the door slam in my face again. Next to no feedback here is making sense, I'm sorry to say.

@zzmondo1 You keep asking us if and why you should keep on doing your PhD only to dismiss it all because you already made up your mind. Why waste everyone's time then? That you don’t feel like continuing your PhD does not change that you have no job. If that makes no sense to you that various kinds of not actually having a job means not having a job, I am really at a loss what you are actually looking for - it certainly doesn’t look like you are looking for honest feedback that doesn’t match the decision you already made. In that case please stop asking for it.

@MisterMiyagi Idk what to say if this sounds dismissive. Point is that none of what I'm hearing is convincing at all. I can easily see a scenario where I find something through vocational rehabilitation next month, only for them to reject me b/c I'm a PhD student or they see I have a PhD on the way and think I'll be "bored" because I'll have it. I'll be brutally honest, I wanted to do stuff like an undergrad research assistant for the rest of my life, which is why I kept going further in my education. If I knew how unreasonable PhD expectations are, even for PhD jobs, I wouldn't have done it.

@zzmondo1 That’s interesting but doesn’t change that you don’t have a job. If you actually make the necessary moves to get one and then actually get one you can weight a) having a job versus b) doing your PhD. But that is not where you are right now so you can only weight a) not having a job versus b) doing your a PhD. This includes especially whether they won’t see you did a PhD for years only to then drop out and think you’ll be bored by their job if even a PhD isn’t interesting enough for you.

@zzmondo1 Put another way, it is completely unclear why you "can easily see a scenario" that matches your already made decision but none that go counter to it. As you admit yourself, you have next to no experience actually getting such a job, have no confidants with experience in getting one, and find the hired help for getting one unsatisfactory. Yet, still, your replies show you make extensive assumptions about what actually goes into decisions on who actually gets such a job. I’ll be brutally honest, you should not trust your assumptions this much.

@MisterMiyagi Vocational rehabilitation will be the main entity that's going to help me get one. I get there's no guarantees, but I don't want to roll the dice wasting my time on my PhD either (especially since I'm working for free on it at this point). Doubly so now that the PhD won't give me any sort of edge for the jobs I want and can actually backfire. Even if I don't have a job now, I need to open my schedule for one. Folks have always said "treat looking for a job like a full time job." I can't exactly follow the former advice given a PhD is full time in of itself.

@zzmondo1 academic job search is not the same as non-academic job search. In the former a PhD is nearly assumed; the latter it is not.

@Allure I realize that an academic job search and non-academic one aren't the same, but I'm not following how that changes the point in the last comment I made exactly. It doesn't change that me being a student was a variable that got in the way of getting a suitable job at one point. Doing a PhD is also taking away time from the job search itself instead. I'm not sure if your point is that those looking for academic jobs work on their PhD at the same time or what, but even then my visiting full time instructor position I had last academic year was too much and I didn't graduate then.
